# add embedded elements in fckeditor plugin

Tags: fckeditor

I am try to create a new fckeditor plugin similar to fck flash plugin, that will write html in the following format

```
<object id="id">
</object>
<script type="text/javascript">
    someJavascriptcode();
</script>
```

I can create object element using

```
e = FCK.EditorDocument.createElement( 'object' ) ;
SetAttribute( e, 'id', 'id1' ) ;
```

how do I wrap the javascript code (as html text or something)

```
oEditor.FCK.InsertHtml('<p>test</p>');
```

works, but when I wrap the javascript code (with imports), it does not work, html html code is not inserted.

ok. looks like fckeditor is removing the script tags.. how do I stop this behavior.

Comment: ok. looks like fckeditor is removing the script tags.. how do I stop this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add by adding javascript on the protected source on fckconfig.js file

```
FCKConfig.ProtectedSource.Add( /<javascript>[\s\S]*?&lt;\/javascript&gt;/g );
```

Comment: and also adding empty div around the javascript code seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works in the regex tester anyway.

```
FCKConfig.ProtectedSource.Add( /<script>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/g );
```